# How do i make the SVG precisely the size of the letters only?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have the following SVG in my Inkscape:

[image: The letters "GAUTAM" across the top of the page]

Now when I save this SVG in my HTML file like below, it takes up a lot of space. I want the SVG to be the size of the letters only. How do I do this in Inkscape?

```
<svg
           xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
           xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
           xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
           xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
           xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
           width="210mm"
           height="297mm"
           viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
           id="svg2"
           version="1.1"
           inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
           sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg">
          <defs
             id="defs4" />
          <sodipodi:namedview
             id="base"
             pagecolor="#ffffff"
             bordercolor="#666666"
             borderopacity="1.0"
             inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
             inkscape:pageshadow="2"
             inkscape:zoom="0.35"
             inkscape:cx="-83.571429"
             inkscape:cy="520"
             inkscape:document-units="px"
             inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
             showgrid="false"
             inkscape:window-width="1366"
             inkscape:window-height="705"
             inkscape:window-x="-8"
             inkscape:window-y="-8"
             inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
          <metadata
             id="metadata7">
            <rdf:RDF>
              <cc:Work
                 rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type
                   rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                <dc:title></dc:title>
              </cc:Work>
            </rdf:RDF>
          </metadata>
          <g
             inkscape:label="Layer 1"
             inkscape:groupmode="layer"
             id="">
            <g
               inkscape:label="Layer 1"
               inkscape:groupmode="layer"
               id="layer1" fill="orange" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
               transform="translate(60,60)">
              <path
                 d="m 28.168945,27.553711 27.729492,0 0,34.628906 q -11.293945,3.867188 -24.829101,3.867188 -14.853516,0 -22.9833985,-8.613282 Q 0,48.823242 0,32.871094 0,17.314453 8.8769531,8.6572266 17.753906,0 33.75,0 q 6.064453,0 11.425781,1.1425781 5.405274,1.1425782 9.404297,2.9003906 L 49.086914,17.666016 q -6.943359,-3.427735 -15.249023,-3.427735 -7.602539,0 -11.777344,4.965821 -4.13086,4.921875 -4.13086,14.106445 0,9.008789 3.735352,13.754883 3.779297,4.702148 10.854492,4.702148 3.867188,0 7.119141,-0.74707 l 0,-10.063477 -11.469727,0 0,-13.40332 z"
                 id="path4141"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              <path
                 d="m 108.41309,65.170898 -3.16407,-12.041015 -20.87402,0 -3.251953,12.041015 -19.072266,0 20.961914,-64.51171831 23.159185,0 21.22558,64.51171831 -18.98437,0 z M 101.64551,38.891602 98.876953,28.344727 Q 97.910156,24.829102 96.503906,19.248047 95.141602,13.666992 94.702148,11.25 q -0.395507,2.241211 -1.582031,7.382812 -1.142578,5.141602 -5.141601,20.25879 l 13.666994,0 z"
                 id="path4143"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              <path
                 d="m 189.00879,0.92285156 0,38.67187544 q 0,12.612304 -7.16309,19.555664 -7.11914,6.899414 -20.5664,6.899414 -13.13965,0 -20.21485,-6.723633 -7.03125,-6.723633 -7.03125,-19.335938 l 0,-39.06738244 17.44629,0 0,37.70507844 q 0,6.811523 2.54883,9.887695 2.54883,3.076172 7.51465,3.076172 5.31738,0 7.69043,-3.032227 2.41699,-3.076172 2.41699,-10.019531 l 0,-37.61718744 17.3584,0 z"
                 id="path4145"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              <path
                 d="m 230.93262,65.170898 -17.3584,0 0,-50.05371 -15.68848,0 0,-14.19433644 48.69141,0 0,14.19433644 -15.64453,0 0,50.05371 z"
                 id="path4147"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              <path
                 d="m 295.26855,65.170898 -3.16406,-12.041015 -20.87402,0 -3.25195,12.041015 -19.07227,0 20.96191,-64.51171831 23.15918,0 21.22559,64.51171831 -18.98438,0 z m -6.76757,-26.279296 -2.76856,-10.546875 q -0.9668,-3.515625 -2.37305,-9.09668 -1.3623,-5.581055 -1.80175,-7.998047 -0.39551,2.241211 -1.58203,7.382812 -1.14258,5.141602 -5.14161,20.25879 l 13.667,0 z"
                 id="path4149"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
              <path
                 d="m 349.2334,65.170898 -13.13965,-46.274414 -0.39551,0 q 0.92285,11.821289 0.92285,18.369141 l 0,27.905273 -15.38086,0 0,-64.24804644 23.11524,0 13.40332,45.61523444 0.35156,0 13.13965,-45.61523444 23.15918,0 0,64.24804644 -15.95215,0 0,-28.168945 q 0,-2.197266 0.044,-4.87793 0.0879,-2.680664 0.61523,-13.139648 l -0.39551,0 -12.96386,46.186523 -16.52344,0 z"
                 id="path4151"
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

How do I make the SVG precisely the size of the letters only?

Comment: In inkscape -> Document Properties -> Page -> Custom size, you have an option to resize page to contents. Does that help?

Comment: @Juancho AWESOOOOOOOOOOOOOOME !! Please add it as an answer ! :D :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Mark the text
- Shift-Ctrl-D = Document settings
- Fit page size to content
- One more button hit

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Even more quick :
Select text objet with select tool (s) > hold Shift-Ctrl-R
This resizes the page to the selected object.
Margins are not editable : if you want to edit margins, use Shift-Ctrl-D method described.

Answer (score 0):

In the current (May 2023) stable release of Inkscape 1.2.2 you can also select the text box, or any combination of objects, then do as follows:

1. Hit the *Create and Edit Document Pages* tool [image] in the tool bar
2. Then in the tool controls along the top, hit the *Fit Page to Current Selection* button [image]

You can also manually edit the page size afterwards using this same  tool, for example if you want to add margins, you can click and drag the corner handles of the page to resize it.